# Problems Compiling PHP with SSH2 pecl extension for Windows

Tags: php, windows, ssh, compilation, php-extension

First, I am not a programmer. I am a Network Admin who has been asked to compile PHP for our web designer with SSH2 enabled.

I have been following this walk-through to compile PHP for Windows:
https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild

To compile, I am using:
Microsoft Visual C++ Studio 2008 Express
Microsoft Windows SDK 6.1

I have downloaded all mandatory [libraries](https://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/libs#extensions_and_their_libraries) and libraries needed for SSH2. I have extracted and placed them in the 'deps' folder. I have also downloaded the SSH2 extension code and placed it in a 'pecl' folder I created in the 'x86' directory.

It looks like the compiler is not finding the libraries I have added. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Here are some of errors I get when attempting to compile using the following command:

```
C:\php-sdk\php53dev\vc9\x86\php5.3-201107071830>configure --enable-cli --with-ss
h2
```

---

```
Checking for library libjpeg_a.lib;libjpeg.lib ... <not found>
WARNING: gd not enabled; libraries and headers not found

Checking for zlib.h ...  <not found>
Checking for zlib.h ...  <not found>
WARNING: zip not enabled; libraries and headers not found


Checking for library libiconv_a.lib ... <not found>
Checking for library libiconv.lib ... <not found>
Checking for library iconv_a.lib ... <not found>
Checking for library iconv.lib ... <not found>
WARNING: iconv support can't be enabled, libraries or headers are missing

Checking for library zlib_a.lib;zlib.lib ... <not found>
WARNING: zlib support can't be enabled, zlib is missing


Checking for library libssh2_a.lib;libssh2.lib ... <not found>
WARNING: ssh2 not enabled: libraries or headers not found

Checking for library libxml2_a_dll.lib;libxml2_a.lib ... ..\deps\libxml2-2.7.3.w
in32\lib\libxml2_a_dll.lib
Checking for library libiconv_a.lib;iconv_a.lib;libiconv.lib;iconv.lib ... <not
found>

WARNING: libxml support can't be enabled, iconv or libxml are missing

WARNING: simplexml not enabled; libraries and headers not found

WARNING: xml support can't be enabled, libraries or headers are missing

WARNING: dom support can't be enabled, libxml is not enabled
```

Comment: I think you need to show the compiler where the library path is. Then the compiler should at least find those libs you've downloaded.

Comment: Does anyone know have to show the compiler where the library path is? I can't seem to find anything that works. I am using Windows SDK command line. When I add the library path in Visual C++ 2008 Express' graphical interface, it does not fix the problem... Thank you

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I ran into similar problems except my issues come out of the command line as LNK issue :

Comment: Creating library Release_TS\php_ssh2.lib and object Release_TS\php_ssh2.exp
libssh2_a.lib(kex.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BN_CTX_free
referenced in function _diffie_hellman_sha1
libssh2_a.lib(kex.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BN_clear_fre
e referenced in function _diffie_hellman_sha1

Comment: I'm on a Windows 7 box but otherwise I have done exactly what you did. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 but it still uses VC++ 9 for compiling.

Answer (score 2):

For SSH2:
(updated URL, we put all releases there, under pecl/snaps, some snapshots build can be found too).

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/

For the error in your build, you are missing all default libs. But if all you want is ssh2, use:

configure --disable-all --enable-cli --with-ss2=shared

(zts or nts may require the zts option as well)

Comment: This definitely helped and I found what I needed there for php 5.4 but how would anyone otherwise KNOW about this? Also, wouldn't it compile ? Please see a comment I posted on the original post. I'm pretty sure I had everything right but the linker couldn't resolve external symbols in the libssh2_a.lib files for some reason. Well, thank you, but I would GREATLY appreciate any feedback you can give me about my linker issues.

Answer (score 0):

Pierre is doing some builds and makes them available over here: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/, as the [official place](http://windows.php.net/download/) is being worked on.

If you need something specific, contact him on IRC: #php.pecl @ efnet. Usually he is willing to invest some time helping out with builds.

Anyway there are some builds for `ssh2`, just CTRL+F in your browser after it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing dependencies, namely [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/). You will have to compile it first and then put the includes in the include path and the lib file in the lib path. For the PHP SDK, this are, respectively, `deps/lib` and `deps/include`.

Then run `configure` again.